# xdebug не работает на Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker, xdebug

После того как я перешел с  Docker Machine на Docker for Mac, у меня перестал работать xdebug. Проблема в том что порт 9000 на хосте недоступен из контейнера.
Конфигурация xdebug:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=172.18.0.1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

В логах следующее:

```
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.18.0.1:9000.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

Контейнер в котором установлен xdebug запускается с помощью Docker Compose
**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    image: <image with php and xdebug>
    ports:
      - 80:80
    # - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
      - ./xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Comment: Можете показать конфиги docker?

Comment: по умолчанию, в докере все порты закрыты.Поэтому, если Вам нужен какой то порт - явно укажите. Скорее всего нужно просто добавить порт

 ports:
      - 80:80
      - 9000:9000

Comment: @АндрейТаланин добавил docker-compose.yml

Comment: скорее всего, кто то его использует. Но кто мешает на хостовой машине использовать другой порт. в настройке портов  композера не объязательно указывать одинаковые порты.

Comment: @KoVadim , именно так у меня работало на Docker Machine. Теперь на Docker for Mac, когда я добавляю 9000:9000, xdebug клиент (в моем случае IDE PhpStorm) не может начать слушать этот порт, ругаясь на то что он занят

Comment: @KoVadim если я в docker-compose.yml укажу например 9000:9001 , тогда какой порт мне нужно прописать в настройках xdebug PhpStorm и какой в xdebug.remote_port ?

Comment: у параметра port следующий формат - `host:container`. Поэтому, нужно наверно указывать так `9001:9000`, Внутри контейнера ничего не трогать, а вот тому, кто подключается к xdebug - указать 9001.

Comment: @KoVadim при таких настройках подключится к xdebug на порт 9001 не получится, так как он будет занят - это особенность появилось после перехода на Docker for Mac, раньше при использовании Docker Machine (VirtualBox) такого не было, так как docker жил на отдельной виртуалке и не был нативным как сейчас

Comment: тогда используйте любой другой порт. Или они также стают "вдруг занятыми"?

Comment: @KoVadim да все верно

Comment: Значит что то делаете не так.

Comment: На каком айпи висит результирующий контейнер и к какому айпи привязывается IDE при публикации порта 9000?

Comment: @Etki контейнер висит на 0.0.0.0, в настройках IDE можно задать только порт для xdebug.

Comment: @ShubnikovAlexey он не может висеть на 0.0.0.0, у него есть конкретный айпи (найти можно через docker inspect). Для xdebug надо так или иначе посмотреть текущие сокеты, там будет указано, на каком айпи был поднят сокет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя проблема заключалась в том, что в Docker for Mac нет возможности подключения к хосту из контейнера. Это возможно связано с ограничениями docker в OSX. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146986/3201727) можно найти более подробную информацию по данной проблеме и [способ решения](https://gist.github.com/ralphschindler/535dc5916ccbd06f53c1b0ee5a868c93).